# Queue variadic push in C

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I have got a question about the use of varadic functionality in a queue implementation written in C language. In particular I need to write a multi-push function to store structures into the queue.

**code_generator.h**

```
typedef enum
{
    NOP,
    START, END,
    ADD, MIN, MULT, DIV,
    ..., // others similar stuffs
    LABEL,
    LE, GE, LT, GT,
    AND, OR,
    DECREMENT
} p_operator;
typedef struct code
{
    p_operator operator;
    p_argument argument;

    struct code * next;

} *p_code;


typedef struct queue
{
    unsigned int length;
    struct code * head;
    struct code * tail;
} p_queue;
```

Don't worry about p_operator and p_argument, the first one is an enum and the second one is a typical union used to store different type of data.
I tried two different implementations but no one works.

### First method (number of arguments unknown)

```
p_queue pqueue_push(p_queue queue, p_code code, ...)
{
    p_code temp;
    va_list vars;

    va_start(vars, code);
    printf("PUSH 1\n");

    for(temp = code; temp != NULL; temp = va_arg(vars, p_code))
    {
        printf("PUSH 2 OPERATOR: %d\n", temp->operator);

        if(queue.length == 0)
        {
            printf("PUSH 3\n");
            queue.tail = queue.head = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("PUSH 4\n");
            p_code swap = queue.tail;
            swap->next = temp;
            queue.tail = swap->next;
        }

        queue.length = queue.length + 1;

        printf("PUSH 5 : %d\n", queue.length);
    }

    printf("PUSH 6\n");
    va_end(vars);

    return queue;
}
```

In this case the program prints everything but the loop is executed one more time (why?) and, obviously, stores in the queue something that doesn't exist.

### Second method (number of arguments known)

```
p_queue pqueue_push(p_queue queue, int nargs, p_code code, ...)
{
    int i;
    p_code temp;
    va_list vars;

    va_start(vars, code);
    printf("PUSH 1 ARGS SIZE: %d\n", nargs);

    for(i = 0; i < nargs; i++)
    {
        temp = va_arg(vars, p_code);
        printf("PUSH 2 OPERATOR: %d\n", temp->operator);

        if(queue.length == 0)
        {
            printf("PUSH 3\n");
            queue.tail = queue.head = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("PUSH 4\n");
            p_code swap = queue.tail;
            swap->next = temp;
            queue.tail = swap->next;
        }

        // Aumenta la dimensione dello queue
        queue.length = queue.length + 1;

        printf("PUSH 5 : %d\n", queue.length);
    }

    printf("PUSH 6\n");
    va_end(vars);

    return queue;
}
```

In this second case the console shows segmentation fault at `"PUSH 2"` and it means that `temp->operator` is `NULL` (but it doesn't make any sense if the first one method works fine over the same parameters).

This fragment of code is that I run in my main function (I don't think that you need to know all the dependeces, prototypes, etc):

```
p_stack stack_temp = pstack_constructor();

// method 1
pstack_push(stack_temp, pcode_constructor_op(START));
// or method 2
pstack_push(stack_temp, 1, pcode_constructor_op(START));
```

**result method 1**

```
OPERATOR 1
PUSH 2 OPERATOR: 1
PUSH 3
PUSH 4
PUSH 5
PUSH 2 OPERATOR: 1398167381
PUSH 4
PUSH 5
PUSH 6
```

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

**result method 2**

```
OPERATOR 1
PUSH 1 ARGS SIZE: 1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**Other functions used in the code**

```
p_queue pqueue_constructor()
{
    p_queue queue;
    queue.length = 0;
    queue.head = queue.tail = NULL;
    return queue;
}

p_code pcode_constuctor()
{
    p_code code = ((p_code) malloc(sizeof(struct code)));
    code->operator = NOP;
    code->next = NULL;
    return code;
}

p_code pcode_constructor_op(p_operator operator)
{
    p_code code = pcode_constuctor();
    code->operator = operator;
    printf("OPERATOR %d\n", code->operator);
    return code;
}
```

#### NOTES

- `p_queue` and `p_code` are always inizializated
- Cast `va_arg(vars, p_code)` dont' change anything
- p_queue is not a pointer, "p" remember me the concept of "pcode" (p_queue contains p_code)

Comment: Is `p_queue` supposed to be a pointer? Otherwise the structure you pass to the functions will be *copied* and you will only modify the copies.

Comment: If the problem is the variable arguments function then make a minimal example that deals with that problem and omit the unnecessary struct, queue, parts.

Comment: Also, how do you call these functions? can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to make the function accept an array of queue members and the length of the array, obviating the need to use var args altogether?

Comment: I hope that those edit could explain better my problem (sorry, english is not my language and the code talks better than me).

Comment: @nitzanms uhm, could be a valid alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the first version, it relies on there being a `NULL` pointer to terminate the argument list, and you don't provide such a terminating `NULL` pointer in the call meaning you will have *undefined behavior* when you go beyond the passed arguments.

The solution is *very* simple, just add a `NULL` pointer in the call:

```
pstack_push(stack_temp, pcode_constructor_op(START), NULL);
```

---

As for the crash in the second version, you forget that the first `p_code` argument you should use is the `code` argument, and you should only get the next argument last in the loop just like you do in the first function.

That means that the `p_code` pointer you dereference is the *second* `p_code` pointer passed, but you don't pass a second pointer leading to undefined behavior and the crash.

Comment: This solution is not very elegant, but simple. Thank you